# derivative of a function given as an integral with kernel

Tags: calculus

If the function $f(u)(x)$ is given as $f(u) = \int_{\Gamma} g(x,y) u(y) dy$, what is the derivative $df/du$?

Comment: Formally, your function $f$ is linear in $u$. Do you know what is the derivative of a (continuous) linear function?

Comment: Perhaps math.SE would be a better site for the question.

Answer (score 2):

The Gâteaux derivative of $f$ at $u$ along $v$ is
$$
Df_u(v) = f(v).
$$
Note that the derivative does not depend on $u$. Hence it is also the Fréchet derivative of $f$. Note that we are implicitly assuming that the kernel $g$ is so that $f$ is a bounded linear map between the relevant function spaces you are interested in.